# Memory Leak trackdown

Tags: rhel, memory, nginx, tomcat, memory-leaks

I have a server running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7.  The server runs a number of java processes including a tomcat server with nginx webserver.  The server has 12 GB of ram allocated to it.

Upon immediate startup the server shows to be using 1289 MB of ram (free -m -/+ buffers/cache line)... output below.

A "ps aux" on server startup shows the memory usage of all processes being a total of 1,290,996 k of memory (The RSS column)... The 2 numbers are pretty close.

After 2 days of uptime free -m now shows us using 10,698 MB of memory while "ps aux" totals up to 8,345,352 k for all processes.

We've attempted to stop/kill each process one by one and even with an absolute bare minimum number of things running (No Tomcat, no Java, no Nginx) we never recover the "Missing" ~2GB of ram.. The only thing we've found to recover the missing memory is to reboot the server.  If the server goes more than 3-4 days without a reboot it starts eating into swap space which eventually causes high CPU usage and the java applications running on it to crawl to a standstill.

I should also mention that this server is running as a virtual machine using VMWare.

Free -m output on startup:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         11852       1787      10064          0         28        468
-/+ buffers/cache:       1289      10562 
Swap:         8191          0       8191
```

Free -m output after 2 days uptime

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         11852      11625        226          0        146        779
-/+ buffers/cache:      10698       1153 
Swap:         8191         43       8148
```

What can I do to help diagnose where the "Missing" memory goes to so that I can resolve the issue.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you total the output of `ps aux`? Do you have a tmpfs or ramfs mounted somewhere? Perhaps on `/tmp`?

Comment: I just dumped it into a file and imported that into excel and totaled the column.. very low-tech

We do use tmpfs on the server